# How to find which level causes a crash in Android

Tags: android

I have a small game which has a few levels. In the google play console, I am getting crashes in the Game-Fragment but it's hard for me to find which level is causing the crash. The first few levels look okay and tested. I am just wondering what is best/standard approach to get the crash along with the level ID/some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different good libraries that allow you to improve logging of the exceptions, one of them is Crashlytics from Google.

With Crashlytics, you can catch exceptions that are happening with following code and log it(and include custom parameters in the message variable):

```
try {
    methodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Crashlytics.log(priority, tag, message);
    // additional handling of your exception
}
```

You can improve your logging this way to include all kind of helpful information. See documentation page for details:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports